# Why is the value of information gain negative?

Tags: decision-trees

Here is a sample dataset. I have to calculate the Information gain in `Variable`. Am I missing anything as information gain should not be negative?

| Variable | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Positive |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val1 | Negative |
| Val2 | Positive |
| Val2 | Positive |
| Val2 | Positive |
| Val2 | Negative |
| Val2 | Negative |
| Val2 | Negative |
| Val2 | Negative |

$$
\text{### Step 1: Calculate Entropy Before Split (Entropy}(S_{\text{before}}))
\text{Entropy}(S_{\text{before}}) = -\frac{15}{24} \log_2\left(\frac{15}{24}\right) - \frac{9}{24} \log_2\left(\frac{9}{24}\right) \\
\text{Entropy}(S_{\text{before}}) \approx 0.954
$$

$$
\text{### Step 2: Calculate Entropy After Split by Gender (Entropy}(S_{\text{Male}}) \text{and Entropy}(S_{\text{Female}}))
\text{Entropy}(S_{\text{Male}}) = -\frac{10}{17} \log_2\left(\frac{10}{17}\right) - \frac{7}{17} \log_2\left(\frac{7}{17}\right) \\
\text{Entropy}(S_{\text{Male}}) \approx 0.977
$$

$$
\text{Entropy}(S_{\text{Female}}) = -\frac{3}{7} \log_2\left(\frac{3}{7}\right) - \frac{4}{7} \log_2\left(\frac{4}{7}\right) \\
\text{Entropy}(S_{\text{Female}}) \approx 0.985
$$

$$
\text{### Step 3: Calculate Information Gain}
\text{Information Gain} = \text{Entropy}(S_{\text{before}}) - \frac{17}{24} \text{Entropy}(S_{\text{Male}}) - \frac{7}{24} \text{Entropy}(S_{\text{Female}}) \\
\text{Information Gain} \approx 0.954 - 0.692 - 0.287 \\
\text{Information Gain} \approx -0.025
$$

Comment: I think you should re-count your numbers in step 1.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It looks good to me. Did you see any issue there?

Comment: Yes, I did. How many "positive"s do you think you have in the right-hand column?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Got it thanks